# Magento Listrak Integration

Tags: magento2, javascript, integration

I am looking for Magento 2.4 and Listrak Email Marketing Integration.

I came across one [extension](https://marketplace.magento.com/listrak-listrak-remarketing.html) on this but the Listrak team mentioned that they won't support this extension anymore.

As per the Listrak, they provided a JS [integration document](https://help.listrak.com/en/articles/4820523-javascript-website-integration-installation).

I am not clear on how to make this work with Magento 2.4.

Is anyone done this before?

Answer (score 0):

There is an installation [giude](https://help.listrak.com/en/articles/2308133-integration-guide-magento-2). But don't use Magento Native integration to set up, it didn't work for us. We just filled the Merchant Id manually. Then set Track with Listrak to yes and it should work.
[image]